# Pick a red ball probability question

Tags: probability

A person can see a ball and has to pick a red ball out of a green and a red ball. There is 8% chance of a person to be color blind (can not differentiate between red and green). If that person is not colorblind his chances are 100% and if he is then 50%.

What are the chances a random person will select a red ball?

I think there is 4% chance that a random person will pick a green ball and 96% that he will pick red.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. It is $4\%$ for incorrectly picking green, and $96\%$ for correctly picking red, by way of the Law of Total Probability. $$\begin{align}8\%\cdot50\%+92\%\cdot 0\% &= 4\%\\[2ex]8\%\cdot 50\%+92\%\cdot 100\%&=96\%\end{align}$$